# WCF REST Service support cross-domain calls from jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, wcf, azure, cross-domain

I built a WCF REST Service running on Azure based on [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781021.aspx). A mobile web app consumes this REST API using jQuery Mobile. The mobile web client calls from a different domain than the REST Service which results in a cross-domain violation. [This article describes exactly my situation and a possible solution](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2011/07/02/ajax-cross-domain-jquery-wcf-web-api-or-mvc-windows-azure/).

Unfortunately the main device for this mobile web app is an iPhone which doesn't run Flash. Does anyway know of any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will it work if you set the header access-control in the header of the REST service.

PHP example...

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost,http://www.example.com,http://example.com'); ?>
```

Or search for Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I was having the issue when using jquery .load for online pages.